# Google assistant media player goes away on pause

Tags: actions-on-google

**BRIEF :**

I have created Google assistant application that plays music using **Google Action Builder**. On specific command, it triggers a webhook. Webhook contains **MediaResponse**
OR **Media** from **'@assistant/conversation'** Library and the code is following

```
conv.add(new Media({
        mediaType: 'AUDIO',
        start_offset: `3.000000001s`,
        mediaObjects: [{
            name: music,
            description: 'This is example of code ',
            url: `https://example.com`,
            image: {
                large: {
                    url: 'https://example.com'
                },
            }
        }]
    }));
```

It is running well on android and the emulator .

**ISSUE :**

- When I pause the music (USING PAUSE BUTTON), the Media player goes away.
- What should I do to keep the media player so that I can resume the music?

Any information regarding this would be appreciated & Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**: It works well for showing media player and plays music but if you click pause button it goes away for both above devices(Android/Test Emulator).

Comment: Where are you seeing this pause behavior?

Comment: @NickFelker I am seeing this pause behavior on Test Emulator as well as Android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding acknowledgment to it fixed the issue.

```
app.handle('media_status', (conv) => {
    const mediaStatus = conv.intent.params.MEDIA_STATUS.resolved;
    switch (mediaStatus) {
        case 'FINISHED':
            conv.add('Media has finished playing.');
            break;
        case 'FAILED':
            conv.add('Media has failed.');
            break;
        case 'PAUSED' || 'STOPPED':
            if (conv.request.context) {
                // Persist the media progress value
                const progress = conv.request.context.media.progress;
            }
            // Acknowledge pause/stop
            conv.add(new Media({
                mediaType: 'MEDIA_STATUS_ACK'
            }));
            break;
        default:
            conv.add('Unknown media status received.');
    }
});
```